# How to print similar information as phpinfo() but for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, webserver, php

I've looped over the `Request.ServerVariables` collection in ASP.NET, but it's not as comprehensive as `phpinfo()`.

How can I print all that information, including server software, drivers, etc, for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An empty page with this header should do the trick:

```
<%@ Page Trace="true"  Language="C#" 
    ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Answer (score 12):

http://code.google.com/p/aspnetsysinfo/

> The project is a ASP.Net System Information Prober. It's a single page which trying to get as much as possible of useful hosting information. The concept is similar to PHP page which contains `phpinfo()`...

Comment: For a more concise output, use `System.Web.Helpers.ServerInfo.GetHtml()` as said here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28654251/508823

Answer (score 10):

[`ServerInfo.GetHtml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.serverinfo.gethtml) is basically the same as `phpinfo()`. Not only is the actual returned information extremely similar but also the html presentation. [Here is a live demo!](http://service.magic-mouse.net/WebPage.cshtml)

---

You can also use it even if you're only making a pure Web API app, but letting a controller return a `HttpResponseMessage` like so:

```
    public System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var serverinfo = System.Web.Helpers.ServerInfo.GetHtml().ToHtmlString();
        var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent("<html><body>" + serverinfo + "</body></html>");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

How about using the ASP.Net tracing subsystem?  It allows you to get:

> Control Tree: Control tree presents an
>   HTML representation of the ASP.NET
>   Control Tree. Shows each control's ID,
>   run time type, the number of bytes it
>   took to be rendered, and the bytes it
>   requires in View State and Control
>   State.
>
> Session State: Lists all the keys for
>   a particular user's session, their
>   types and their values.
>
> Application State: Lists all the keys
>   in the current application's
>   Application object and their type and
>   values.
>
> Request Cookies: Lists all the cookies
>   passed in during the page is
>   requested.
>
> Response Cookies: Lists all the
>   cookies that were passed back during
>   the page's response.
>
> Headers Collection: Shows all the
>   headers that might be passed in during
>   the request from the browser,
>   including Accept-Encoding, indicating
>   whether the browser supports the
>   compressed HTTP responses and Accept
>   languages.
>
> Form Collection: Displays a complete
>   dump of the Form Collection and all
>   its keys and values.
>
> QueryString Collection: Displays a
>   dump of the Querystring collection and
>   all its contained keys and values.
>
> Server Variables: A complete dump of
>   name-value pairs of everything that
>   the web server knows about the
>   application.

See [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Tracing-ASP.NET.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The following might work?

```
foreach (string Key in Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys) 
   Response.Write(Key + ": " + Request.ServerVariables[Key] + "<br>");
```

I'm not sure what info phpinfo() spits out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [glimpse](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse).

> [glimpse](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse): A client side Glimpse to your server
>
> What Firebug is for the client, Glimpse does for the server... in other words, a client side Glimpse into whats going on in your server.

Here's the [request tab as shown in the browser](https://web.archive.org/web/20120508210254/http://getglimpse.com/Help/Plugin/Request).
[image]
<sub>(source: [getglimpse.com](http://getglimpse.com/Content/Plugin/Request.jpg))</sub>

There are [other tabs with information](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330024121/http://getglimpse.com:80/Help/), and it's possible to [write plugins](https://web.archive.org/web/20120825184747/http://getglimpse.com:80/Help/CreatingPlugins).

Answer (score 0):

Quick google result:

http://forums.asp.net/p/901862/2087653.aspx

According to them, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer i found, that looks like it covers it covers it, at first sight:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?p=133347
someone scripted it out

Comment: Thanks, but that's for Classic ASP, not ASP.NET.

Comment: actionscript URL is dead. See my answer below for classic ASP solution.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP classic with VBScript (**not ASP.net** - see disclaimer below) there is a `Sub aspinfo()` on [Planet Source Code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCodeAsText.asp?txtCodeId=8048&lngWId=4), to which I've made very minor changes (moving the call to `aspinfo()` and moving the top authorship/comment block).

Here is the source of my modified version of [Dennis Pallett's `aspinfo()`](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCodeAsText.asp?txtCodeId=8048&lngWId=4), which can be saved as `aspinfo.asp` on the webserver in question.

```
<%@ Language="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%

    '**************************************
    ' Name: aspinfo()
    ' Description:aspinfo() is the equivalent of phpinfo(). It displays all kinds of
    '     information about the server, asp, cookies, sessions and several other things in
    '     a neat table, properly formatted.
    ' By: Dennis Pallett (from psc cd)
    '
    '
    ' Inputs:None
    '
    ' Returns:None
    '
    'Assumes:You can include my code in any of your pages and call aspinfo() to show
    '     the information of your server and asp. 
    '
    '**************************************

Sub aspinfo()
    Dim strVariable, strASPVersion
    Dim strCookie, strKey, strSession
    'Retrieve the version of ASP
    strASPVersion = ScriptEngine & " Version " & ScriptEngineMajorVersion & "." & ScriptEngineMinorVersion
%>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
    a { text-decoration: none; }
    a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
    h1 { font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold;}
    h2 { font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold;}
    body, td { font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }
    th { font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; }
    //--></style>
    <title>aspinfo()</title></head>
    <body>
    <div align="center">
    <table width="80%" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFAE" align="left" colspan="2">
            <h3>ASP (<%= strASPVersion %>)</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h3>Server Variables</h3>
    <table width="80%" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<%
    For Each strVariable In Request.ServerVariables
      Response.write("<tr>")
      Response.write("<th width=""30%"" bgcolor=""#FFFFAE"" align=""left"">" & strVariable & "</th>")
      Response.write("<td bgcolor=""#FFFFD9"" align=""left"">" & Request.ServerVariables(strVariable) & "&nbsp;</td>")
      Response.write("</tr>")
    Next 'strVariable
%>
    </table>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h3>Cookies</h3>
    <table width="80%" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<%
    For Each strCookie In Request.Cookies
        If Not Request.Cookies(strCookie).HasKeys Then
            Response.write("<tr>")
            Response.write("<th width=""30%"" bgcolor=""#FFFFAE"" align=""left"">" & strCookie & "</th>")
            Response.write("<td bgcolor=""#FFFFD9"" align=""left"">" & Request.Cookies(strCookie) & "&nbsp;</td>")
            Response.write("</tr>")
        Else
            For Each strKey In Request.Cookies(strCookie)
                Response.write("<tr>")
                Response.write("<th width=""30%"" bgcolor=""#FFFFAE"" align=""left"">" & strCookie & "(" & strKey & ")</th>")
                Response.write("<td bgcolor=""#FFFFD9"" align=""left"">" & Request.Cookies(strCookie)(strKey) & "&nbsp;</td>")
                Response.write("</tr>")
            Next
        End If
    Next
%>
    </table>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h3>Session Cookies</h3>
    <table width="80%" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
<%
    For Each strSession In Session.Contents
            Response.write("<tr>")
            Response.write("<th width=""30%"" bgcolor=""#FFFFAE"" align=""left"">" & strSession & "</th>")
            Response.write("<td bgcolor=""#FFFFD9"" align=""left"">" & Session(strSession) & "&nbsp;</td>")
            Response.write("</tr>")
    Next
%>
    </table>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h3>Other variables</h3>
    <table width="80%" border="0" bgcolor="#000000" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
    <tr><th width="30%" bgcolor="#FFFFAE" align="left">Session.sessionid</th><td bgcolor="#FFFFD9"><%= Session.sessionid %></td></tr>
    <tr><th width="30%" bgcolor="#FFFFAE" align="left">Server.MapPath</th><td bgcolor="#FFFFD9"><%= Server.MapPath ("/") %></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
<%
End Sub
aspinfo()
%>
```

---

*Disclaimer: Note that this was initially submitted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10899562) to [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4370704/4228193), but it was suggested that it be made as an entirely new answer response instead. Note also that, as [frankadelic points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544209/is-there-an-equivalent-to-phpinfo-in-asp-net/4370704#comment4771518_4370704) in a comment to Rob's answer, this response doesn't address the OP's question, as that question was for ASP.net, not ASP classic.*

Answer (score 0):

I realized a simple library to inlude in projects called [InfoPage](https://github.com/zeppaman/info-page). This library show you system info, assembly included in application, build number,and changelogs.

You can simply include it  in your project by nuget, it is quick to integrate and customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a [gist available](https://gist.github.com/mika76/84df6985535c54d9c4a7adffb43e53eb) to add a razor page with phpinfo type information in .net core...