# ASP.NET - how to display server stats / info?

Tags: asp.net

In php there is a function `phpinfo();` which displays a whole load of server stats and config information. What is the equivalent in ASP.NET? is there anything?

cheers

Comment: I think this question should be closed , being a dublicate of "Is there an equivalent to phpinfo() in ASP.NET?"

Answer (score 4):

You can now use [`System.Web.Helpers.ServerInfo.GetHtml()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.serverinfo.gethtml.aspx) (in `System.Web.Helpers.dll`) which returns an HTML table of all the environment variables, very much like phpinfo() does.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.serverinfo.gethtml.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No.

But after enabling tracing for the whole application in the web.config, you can view trace.axd for similiar info.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, but I think the answer to this question will be helpful to you: [How to print similar information as phpinfo() but for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544209/is-there-an-equivalent-to-phpinfo-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

There's not a `phpinfo` style function in ASP.NET. I think you can enable tracing in `Web.config` and navigate to `trace.axd` to see similar stuff.