# Asp.net environment

Tags: asp.net-4.0

Is there a pre-made page that will give some details on the executing machine where the server runs? simple things such as CPU, RAM, and maybe a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be helpful - [How to print similar information as phpinfo() but for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544209/is-there-an-equivalent-to-phpinfo-in-asp-net)