# Asp/asp.net Hosting Info Page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I think it's a stupid queston below.

As I know there is a phpinfo() function to view php hosting as a info page.
Is there a asp/asp.net info page for an asp/asp.net hosting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent to phpinfo() in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544209/is-there-an-equivalent-to-phpinfo-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Dustin Laine, I followed your link above and found the macro script. It should be an answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a page with nothing on it and enable tracing for the page. It won't give you everything you want but [have a look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I created a little plugin for asp.net MVC that show info about application, loaded assemblies, build number and change logs.

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/zeppaman/info-page) and integrate it by include in projects using nuget