# Info Page about ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Please, look at that 2 questions:
[Asp/asp.net Hosting Info Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5254187/48729) and [Is there an equivalent to phpinfo() in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/544209/48729)

Using the info in that 2 questions, I have 2 simple files, "info.php" and "info.aspx", where "info.aspx" simply contains:

```
<%@ Page Trace="true"  Language="C#" 
    ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

and "info.php" contains:

```
<?php echo phpinfo();?>
```

Now, I would like a single page/file solution that show info about **ASP.Net Core and/or .Net Core** - if it is supported, installed, wich version, etc...

Is it possible?

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64607803/11421

Answer (score 2):

It had been an RuntimeInfoPage middleware in Diagnostics (`app.UseRuntimeInfoPage()` ), but it was removed in RTM. There is an open request to restore it back and make more useful: https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/issues/280